What do we know about Krishna's daily routine?
What were his daily rituals, the mantras he used, how and when did he sleep , eat etc , anything that can be learned by his example.
What is the best place to learn about his life, any best references and quotes from the puranas ?

You can check this https://mukundacharan.wordpress.com/eightfold-pastimes-of-lord-krishna/ Lord Krishna’s Daily Activities are given clearly.

This is from the early childhood, not what I intended
